# Does powertop work with Mac OS X Snow Leopard or are there other power profiling utilities?

Tags: snow-leopard, power

I recently came across a blog post highlighting powertop for Linux (see: http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/).  Based on the FAQ, powertop relies on the fact that the Linux kernel is now tickless.  Given a specific Linux kernel requirement, I am doubtful that it will work with the Darwin kernel.  Freshmeat also mentions powertop, but they have a tag suggesting that a POSIX compliant OS can use powertop.  Since FreeBSD is POSIX compliant, I was wondering if anyone had tried powertop on Snow Leopard ?

If not, does anyone know of similar, power profiling tools for Snow Leopard ?  Specifically, power profiling tools that highlight processes consuming power.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: How is this different than "CPU Time" in top or Activity Monitor (assuming all apps are started at roughly the same wall-clock time)?

Comment: @mankoff - CPU time only shows the amount of time consumed by the process. This does not translate into the actual amount of power used by the process.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dtrace` and counting which processes wake and the reason and time, you might be able to get some of the information provided by `powertop`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  DTrace is of use from a sysadmin standpoint, not just as an instrumentation tool for application development ?

Comment: DTrace can indeed be tremendeously useful for sysadmin purposes. It is a rather complex tool, however. And I find the lack of documentation for the OS X implementation frustrating. While the language itself is the same across operating systems, the set of available probes is quite different.

Comment: Thanks Harald!  I saw a book recently, just on DTrace that covered it on other UNIX's and Mac OS.  I may pick it up - it included coverage of the D language.

Comment: Could you add an example about how to do that?